# How to detect enter being pressed in a textbox?

Tags: winforms, textbox

How do i detect when enter is pressed in a textbox in visual studio 2013 forms application??  I've tried using textbox1_OnKeyPress, KeyUp, KeyDown, KeyPress, everything I could find in google searches, and none of it worked... is it a check I have to make in textChanged??

Comment: Please provide some code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in creating an example of your issue.

Comment: KeyDown/Up will work for this, depending on the exact semantics desired. If it "didn't work", then it was done incorrectly - but without code and/or an adequate description of what "didn't work", there really is no way to provide more useful feedback ..

Comment: Did you set the textbox's MultiLine property to be true?

Comment: (Also, [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) will generally not work for such cases: "The KeyPress event is *not raised by noncharacter keys*]; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events." - although I'm not strictly sure if enter is a "non-character"; it might be in a single-line context.)

Comment: Here is the code.. http://pastebin.com/KyMZHxBC

Due to the if statement being commented out, the messagebox should theoretically show when ANY key is let go of, but I can't get it to happen..

Comment: The code also has to make sure the methods are bound in the control event handlers, which can be specified in the designer. Just changing the name won't automatically wire up control events - the method to call must be added as an event handler. (I suspect this is *a* problem, because if it was wired up and the method name was changed, without updating the event handler, then there would have been a compiler error.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a textbox in your form and handle the KeyDown event of that textbox.

```
public class Form1
{
   public Form1()
   { 
       InitializeComponent();
       textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.KeyDownEvent);
   } 
   private void KeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCOde == Keys.Return)
       {
           //Place your code here
       }
   }
}
```